# Sum of the series $\frac{1}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I wish to find sum of a finite and infinite series$$\sum    \frac{1}{n!}$$

I am aware, that this is a standard series and thus has a straight forward (well-known) answer BUT I am not recollecting it.

A hint Please.

Comment: [$e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant))

Comment: for infinite series, it is $e$, otherwise i am afraid there is no closed form available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you remember that $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\ ?$$

Edit: This is the answer for the infinite series.

Edit: The convergence is easy: just apply the ratio test.

Comment: Actually I just want to show the series is convergent. I would not like to go for another more complicated series.  Better if a simple and short answer is available

Comment: Try using the ratio test.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have asked for finite sums too:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^m 1/n! = \frac{e\;\Gamma(m+1,1)}{\Gamma(m+1)},
$$
where $\Gamma(m+1,x) = \int_x^{\infty} t^{m}\,e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t \,$ resp. $\Gamma(m+1)= \int_0^{\infty} t^{m}\,e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t $ are the [(incomplete) $\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

Further you'll find in limit, that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\Gamma(s,x) &=& (s-1)!\, e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
\frac{\Gamma(s,x)}{\Gamma(s)}&=&e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}\\
\lim_{s\to \infty} e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{s-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}&=&e^{-x}e^x=1,
\end{eqnarray} $$
stated by the other answers given.